# Is there a way to filter bulk inserts in mule 4?

Tags: mule, mule4

I'm doing a bulk insert in mule 4 where I want to filter some data.

This is my SQL query now.

```
INSERT INTO Example (AnlaggningId,Objektsnamn) values (:AnlaggningId,:Objektsnamn)
```

I only want to insert the row if Objektsnamn does not contain the substring "Hi". Is there a way to do this in mule 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Transform component before the bulk operation to filter the input, using the [filter()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-filter) function.

Example, assuming the input is a list of records with a field called `Objektsnamn`:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter !($.Objektsnamn contains ("Hi"))
```

Comment: Hi! The input is actually a stream which is the return value of a SELECT query. How would I code that?

Comment: It is the same thing for DataWeave. What's important is the information contained

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to filter the results from the SELECT query with the following syntax.

```
<set-payload value='#[payload filter $.Objektsnamn != "Hi"]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="24c6f187-5e43-4695-809c-1f92e3d489d7" />
```

Comment: That's the same method from my answer however the condition used is "not equal". The question asked for "does not contains". Please update the question if it was not correct.

Comment: Yes I know, but for some reason it did not work with the exact syntax you provided. The () were problematic